# EF does not make changes to the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

`SaveChangesAsync` method in EF doesn't save changes to the database.

```
var mydataout = _dbContext.MyTable
                          .Where(a => a.MyData== context.Message.Data);

if (mydataout.Any())
{
    foreach (var output in mydataout)
    {
        output.IsActive = false;
    }
}
        
var result = await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Here the `SaveChangesAsync` method is not making any changes to the database. I'm using ASP.NET Core with EF.

Comment: This is rather peculiar thing. A full [mre] would be great. P.S. `mydataout.Any()` a) is redundant 2) will lead to extra database call.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct though. What version of EF are you using? I did a simulation with EF Core 6 it's ok.

Thank's

Comment: EF Core 7.... have also  _dbContext.MyTable.Update(output ); inside the foreach ...

Comment: while debugging i found in the  "mydataout" the IsActive flag is not set to false.(after the forloop execution it is still true)