# Unable to update Data using EF Executeupdate and savechangesmethod

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I am trying to update a single property from the filteredData result .filteredData contains more than one records and want to update IsActive property to False. I have tried to update using EF 7 ExecuteUpdateAsync method but the same didnt work when i have include in my query.

```
var filteredData=  _dbContext.Table1.Where(a => a.Table1Id == Id)
                        .Include(m => m.Table2)
                        .ThenInclude(am => am.Table3)
                        .ThenInclude(ms => ms.Table4)
                        .Where(t => t.Table2.Any(x => x.Table3.Table4.Code != "CO"));
                     //.ExecuteUpdateAsync(a => a.SetProperty(u => u.IsActive, false));
```

filteredData results more than one record.

```
            if (filteredData!= null)
            {
                foreach (var rowData in filteredData)
                {
                    rowData .IsActive = false;
                }
                //    _dbContext.Table1.Update(rowData );
            }
            _dbContext.Table1.UpdateRange(filteredData);
            var result = await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Here commented code is Executeupdateasync method and also savechangesasync also included.
One thing i noticed is if i remove all the "Include" the data getting update with Executeupdateasync method

Comment: 1) you have already asked that - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75943240/2501279) (though without `ExecuteUpdateAsync` part) 2) are you sure you are using EF 6, which is previous iteration of EF and usually used with .NET Framework 3) please provide a [mre], or at least post the entity and context setup and what database are you using.

Comment: `Include` needed only for loading related data. Remove `Include`s and show which error you have when calling `ExecuteUpdateAsync`.

Comment: If i remove include it works fine.....This check i needed and hence the related data need to be loaded here....Where(t => t.Table2.Any(x => x.Table3.Table4.Code != "CO"));

Comment: basically i need to load relational data and apply the filter code!="CO" and the result of this filtered data's active flag need to set to false and want to update it back to the DB

Comment: For filter you do not need `Include` at all.

Comment: so how do i filter as there is a connection in Table1 and Table 4

Comment: I can repeat. For generating SQL and WHERE condition EF do not need `Include`. `Include` is for different  thing - loading related entities. You do not load anything, just execute Update.

Comment: I got you.  i will use simple join get my data filtered.

Comment: You don't have to use joins. Just do not use `Include` if you do not want to load data mentioned in `Include`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253006/discussion-between-coder11-b-and-svyatoslav-danyliv).